# How to append a url to an existing mysql entry

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have entries in a mysql database, relating to image locations. Currently the entries only feature the path: "/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/28/image.jpg"

I need to change these to feature the domain as well:" https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/28/image.jpg"

I have searched about on here and found the following attempt at a solution, but it isn't working. Can anyone guide me as to where i'm going wrong?

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET "wpcf-image"=CONCAT ('https://example.com',meta_value) WHERE "wpcf-image" NOT LIKE 'https://example.com%'
```

In mysql, i'm using the "wp_postmeta" table, the field name is "wpcf-image". The "WHERE" string should ensure that the query only runs against entries that don't already conform.

Comment: What is the meta key for your image paths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta
SET meta_value = CONCAT ('https://example.com', meta_value)
WHERE
    meta_key = 'wpcf-image' AND
    meta_value NOT LIKE 'https://example.com%';
```

The `wp_postmeta` table has a sort of key value pair setup.  I think you want to update all meta values, which are `URLs`, corresponding to the `wpcf-image` key.  If so, then you need to update only the `meta_value`, and do that only for the particular `meta_key` of interest.

Comment: Tried this, and it just replaced all the current entries so they only contained "https://example.com" and didn't append it to the beginning.

Comment: This seems unlikely.  For those records affected, the updated value should be `https://example.com` followed by something.  What that something is depends on what was already in the table.

Comment: All working now. Thanks for this. I think i mist have mistyped somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'/wp-content/upload',' https://example.com/wp-content/uploads') where meta_key = 'wpcf-image';
```

use this query